# How to be able to execute pm2 commands with all users using ansible?

Tags: ansible, pm2

I'm setting up a nodeJS server role (ansible) and I want to use pm2 as service manager. I want to be able to execute pm2 commands with all users on the system, after try to give 755 to these files as the root user is the owner I cannot execute pm2 commands with the others users, now I created a group, added all the users and changed the owner to the group, but when loggin to the EC2 instance (Amazon linux) it's giving me this error with all users except root:

```
[PM2][ERROR] Permission denied, to give access to current user:
$ sudo chown user:user /var/project/.pm2/rpc.sock /var/project/.pm2/pub.sock
```

This is part of my ansible role:

```
- name: Adding users to project group
  user: name="{{item}}"
        groups=group
        append=yes
  with_items:
    - user
    - user2
```

and Here I try to change the owner:

```
- file:
    path: "/var/project/.pm2/rpc.sock"
    mode: 0775
    group: group
  become: true

- file:
    path: "/var/project/.pm2/pub.sock"
    mode: 0775
    group: group
  become: true
```

But still getting that message and when I list files:

```
srwxrwxr-x  1 root    root        0 Jan 21 16:05 pub.sock
srwxrwxr-x  1 root    root        0 Jan 21 16:05 rpc.sock
```